# chosen:updated trigger blocks text from being rendered in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am listening to changes in the chosen-generated input element. Somehow when I trigger `chosen:updated`, the text in the input element wont' render.

A simple demo:

```
<div style="width: 400px" class="parent row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <select  multiple="multiple" class="tags"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(".tags").chosen({    
    width: '50%',
});

var select = $(".tags");
var input = $(".parent input");

input.on('input', function() {
    var option = $("<option value='bob'>bob</option>");
    select.append(option);

    // Below causes input to stop rendering text in input element
    select.trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/375wabt7/). I might not be doing this correctly. What I am trying to accomplish is grab the current text after some edit in the input box, send that to server for processing, then render the result as an option in chosen.

How can I do this with chosen? The above method works, just that the text isn't being rendered after a user types something.

Comment: I am afraid you have to use an separate input and a select to achieve what you want, the value of select input is bonded to the select when you add options to it, so the content you typed in will never show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved to using [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) instead. It even supports bootstrap!

Answer (score 0):

You can have the user type something and have it added to the list of select-options when the user presses enter. So like:

```
$(".tags").chosen({    width: '50%',
              });

var select = $(".tags");
var input = $(".parent input");


input.keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        var option = $("<option></option>").html(input.val());
        select.append(option);
        select.trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle with the result.](http://jsfiddle.net/375wabt7/2/)